# Implement a multimap in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, hashmap

I am trying to implement a multimap in Python. I have three fields of each record.

SerialNo, Name, Food

```
1 John Apple
2 Bill Orange
3 Josh Apple
```

Here, `SerialNo` and `Name` will not be duplicated except `Food`.

I can insert one key, value and query on that in my hashmap. But, how to make relations with three values. As, I want to query like,

```
SerialNo s where Food='Apple'
Name where Food='Apple'
Food where Name='Bill'
Get the all stored data (SerialNo, Name, Food)
```

I can make only one index but how to query with each fields.

This is my hashmap to insert data,

```
class HashMap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.store = [None for _ in range(16)]
        self.size = 0

    def put(self, key, value):
        p = Node(key, value)
        key_hash = self._hash(key)
        index = self._position(key_hash)
        if not self.store[index]:
            self.store[index] = [p]
            self.size += 1
        else:
            list_at_index = self.store[index]
            if p not in list_at_index:
                list_at_index.append(p)
                self.size += 1
            else:
                for i in list_at_index:
                    if i == p:
                        i.value = value
                        break
```

I can't use `dict` , I prefer to build the function from scratch for learning purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to implement a database table. This is most naturally implemented as a set of dicts. (But there are libraries with more efficient implementations, like sqlite and pandas)

```
table = {
   dict(zip(('SerialNo', 'Name', 'Food'), row))
   for row in [
      (1, 'John', 'Apple'),
      (2, 'Bill', 'Orange'),
      (3, 'Josh', 'Apple'),
   ]
}
```

You can do your queries as list comprehensions.

```
# SerialNo s where Food='Apple'
[row['Food'] for row in table if row['Food'] == 'Apple']

# Name where Food='Apple'
[row['Name'] for row in table if row['Food'] == 'Apple']

# Food where Name='Bill'
[row['Food'] for row in table if row['Name'] == 'Bill']

# Get the all stored data (SerialNo, Name, Food)
table
```

More complex queries are possible. For large tables, you can make queries more efficient by creating an external index in advance, just like a database engine. Use a dictionary with your lookup keys and point them to your row dicts in the table set.

```
name_index = {row['Name']: row for row in table}

name_index['John']  # {'SerialNo': 1, 'Name': 'John', 'Food': 'Apple'}
```

You could also try a set of named tuples as your table rows instead of dicts for more efficiency. This also lets you use the dot notation for cell access.

---

## New requirement:

> Hi, I can't use dict . I prefer to build the function for learning purpose.

OK, so implement a normal hashtable and use that instead of the native Python dict. If you need multiple indexes use multiple hashtables as above.

---

> But, I have duplicates Food value, how to index on it ?

Think about what a query using this index would return. It's a set of rows that use that food instead of a single row, right? So that's what you use as the value to look up in the index hashtable.

```
{food: {row for row in table if row['Food']==food}
 for food in {row['Food'] for row in table}}
```

You could probably do that a bit more efficiently with a for loop.

```
food_index = {}
for row in table:
    food_index.setdefault(row['Food'], set()).add(row)
```

It may simplify your logic if the unique indexes also return sets of rows instead of a single row. (The set would contain a single row in that case.)

```
name_index = {row['Name']: {row} for row in table}
```

---

I'm still using dicts to demonstrate the approach concisely, but there's no reason you couldn't implement all these features yourself. Even comprehensions can be done with a generator expression inside a function call, e.g.

```
{k:v for k, v in foo}
dict((k, v) for k, v in foo)
```

Those two lines above are functionally equivalent. Of course, if `foo` already contains pairs (the result of a `zip` call, for example), it could be simplified to

```
dict(foo)
```

You can use your own hash table class in place of `dict`.

---

Your multimap implementation can create and store these indexes upon initialization and update the row sets in each index appropriately when rows are added or removed from the table. Mutating a row dict could invalidate the indexes, so it might be more appropriate to make each row an immutable type like a named tuple or the like (if you must, implement it yourself). Then altering a row in the table is just adding a new row and deleting the old one.

Comment: Hi, I can't use dict . I prefer to build the function for learning purpose.

Comment: But, I have duplicates Food value, how to index on it ?